# Julia - Developing package and updating changes without restarting Jupyter Notebook kernel

Tags: module, jupyter-notebook, package, kernel, julia

I'm developing a package in Julia, and I'm using Jupyter Notebook to do some testing. The problem is, every time I make a change to my package, I need to restart the kernel.

I heard that the package Revise.jl is supposed to solve this type of problem, but even after sniffing through the documentation, I didn't quite understand how to properly use it with Jupyter Notebook.

How does one properly avoid restarting the kernel for Jupyter every time one makes a change to the package?

Just to give some more context. I have a folder with the following structure:

```
Manifest.toml
Project.toml
Readme.md
./examples/Notebook.ipynb
./src/function.jl
./src/MyPackage.jl
```

Comment: Doesn't it just work if you run `using Revise` in the first cell of your notebook, before `using MyPackage`? When you modify some source file and re-run a cell in your notebook, doesn't it automatically pick the change? (I just checked it works for `includet`, but was too lazy to check for full-fledged packages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.

So indeed, one just need to use the Revise.jl package.
The reason it wasn’t working for me is that I was importing MyPackage before Revise, and you need to import Revise first. Hence, once I restarted the Kernel and used Revise before MyPackage, things worked flawlessly.

Comment: To avoid needing to remember, you can load Revise automatically whenever you start Julia: https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/config/#Using-Revise-by-default-1